# Is there any way to open facebook.com with another URL?

Tags: facebook

Our admin is blocking facebook.com. Is there any other way to access Facebook, like using a different site or URL?

Also, we can’t open it from a mobile device.

Comment: A simple [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+facebook+when+it+is+blocked) shows an awful lot of alternative solutions. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is: If the admin edited the `hosts` file to block Facebook, you can get access to Facebook by the IP address instead of the domain address. Putting that IP address in your browser directly will bypass the barrier from the `hosts` file. You can get the IP address by pinging facebook.com from your computer. To do so, Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> key (to open the Run command box). Type in the following command and hit Enter.

```
ping facebook.com -t
```

This will open a command prompt and it will show the IP address of facebook.com.

You can also use an online web proxy like [hidemyass.com](http://hidemyass.com).